# How to to check the cycles count in time series data using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cycle-detection, peak-detection

I have a battery voltage data with respect to Datetime, collected data for one month I need to find out the number of cycles of battery hers is my data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K0XspcrpO94mv2wFgW45DzSjAO0Af1uSwmoHHVxDJwI/edit?usp=sharing
since I used peak detection algorithm it is not detecting the cycles correctly is there any way to find the cycles data
here is my code I used

```
import numpy as np
op_col = []
for i in df["voltage"]:
 op_col.append(i)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
x = np.array(op_col)
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peak, _ = find_peaks(x, width=800,prominence=1,height=51)
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(19,8))
plt.plot(x)
plt.xlim(0,45000)
plt.plot(peak, x[peak], "x", color = 'r')
```

here is my out put [image: trouble detecting cycles here]

how can I do it in another way any suggestions.
thanks in advance

Comment: How do you define the cycles? What would be the result on the shown example?

Comment: 0 to 50  and 50 to 0 one cycle